# Not able to install testng in eclipse luna

Tags: eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am using eclipse luna. Below is the details
Eclipse Standard/SDK

Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)
Build id: 20150219-0600

I tried to install testng plugin using following options, but facing issues 
1) Install new software [image: error_testng]

2) Marketplace [image]

Please guide me how to install the plugin.

Comment: Did you press `Yes` or `No` in the last screen ?

Comment: Do you have some kind of error ? Can you access the plugin in eclipse after ?

Comment: @flafoux: message displayed "Cannot complete the request.  See the error log for details."
Error log:HTTP Proxy authentication required.

Comment: I believe you are behind firewall so you will have to do some proxy settings in eclipse to download plugins from marketpalce

Answer (score 0):

> I have gone through the question and screen shots, as per the image, I think you have given the URL in the field (Work with) first and then clicked "Add" button.
>   If I am right as above, then follow the steps
>
> - First click the "Add" button and a pop-up will come with two fields (Name, Location)
> - Give "TestNG" in the name field and the "http://beust.com/eclipse" in the Location field. And click "Ok"

Comment: I did the same thing what you have mentioned. Still the issue persists.

Comment: @Anand, If possible for you then switch to Eclipse Kepler instead of Luna and try.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue, which is now resolved for me.

I went to http://testng.org/doc/download.html , here a link is displayed from which you can check old plug-in versions of TestNG, clicking that will take you to http://beust.com/eclipse-old/ , this page displays list of urls. I selected a version below to latest one and copy pasted that url to Location field in Eclipse and it worked !!!

Hope it helps...